# Javascript select first two from array

Tags: javascript, json

```
O {
    k = 57.690636,
    A = -2.010575000000017,
    type = 'terrible'
}
```

The above currently has `k` and `A` as `keys` but these change periodically. So I was hoping someone could help me fix my problem.

I currently just use `data.k` and `data.A` to get the values from the array but would it be possible to only select the first two and set them into a variable without knowing the key name?

Comment: That's not an array though.  javascript does not support associative arrays.

Comment: `first two`. There are no first two in Objects, as they work based on hash values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the JSON members to an array, and then use it's index..

```
var O = {
  k:57.690636,
  A:-2.010575000000017,
  type:'terrible'
};
var index = [];
for (var x in O) {
   index.push(O[x]);
};
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/124965

Answer (score 1):

Though not the best of method the following would work under the assumption that the properties you are looking for are of type number.

```
var obj = {
    k : 57.690636,
    A : -2.010575000000017,
    type : 'terrible'
};


for (attr in obj)
{
if (typeof obj[attr] === 'number')
{
console.log(obj[attr]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.keys(yourObjectHere)` to get an array of keys, but for a more old-browser-compatible method, try:

```
var keys = [], k;
for( k in yourObjectHere) keys.push(k);
```

You can also break out of your loop once you have the first two if you like.

However you choose to do it, you can now access `yourObjectHere[keys[0]]` and `yourObjectHere[keys[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

The order of the properties of a JavaScript object is undefined by the specification. This means that depending on the implementation, the keys can be returned in any order, so they first two keys can be any two keys in the object.

[for..in](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4)

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.

[Object.keys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14)

> If an implementation defines a specific order of enumeration for the for-in statement, that same enumeration order must be used in step 5 of this algorithm.

The best thing to do is to stabilize the source of those objects to always return the valuable information using the same keys.

---

A random guess would be that you use some minifier that reduces the key length. Perhaps instead of doing

```
var returnedObject = {
  lat : '123',
  long : '456';
}
```

You could do:

```
var returnedObject = {};
returnedObject['lat'] = '123';
returnedObject['long'] = '456';
```

This should prevent minification from changing your key names. If you use an external service, you should ask yourself if that is actual public (meaning data that is intended to be used by you) data or not and if it is not, what is the public alternative.